# mysql complex SUM divided by COUNT

Tags: mysql, count, sum, average

I am not very experienced in mysql so I hope my question isn't too stupid and the lines of code are more or less readable.
The following mysql query delivers the amount of specific content a group of students produced in a group work.

```
SELECT
access_collections.id AS "Group ID", 
access_collections.name AS "Group",
SUM(CASE WHEN system_log.object_subtype="blog" AND system_log.event="create" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Number of blog entries",
SUM(CASE WHEN system_log.object_subtype="comment" AND system_log.event="create" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Number of comments",
SUM(CASE WHEN system_log.object_subtype="discussion_reply" AND system_log.event="create" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Number of discussion replies",
SUM(CASE WHEN system_log.object_subtype="chat_message" AND system_log.event="create" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Number of chat messages",
SUM(CASE WHEN system_log.object_subtype="file" AND system_log.event="create" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Number of uploaded files",
SUM(CASE WHEN system_log.object_subtype="messages" AND system_log.event="create" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Number of messages",

FROM system_log

INNER JOIN access_collection_membership ON access_collection_membership.user_guid=system_log.performed_by_guid
INNER JOIN access_collections ON access_collections.id=access_collection_membership.access_collection_id

GROUP BY access_collections.id
```

Now I want to get the average amount of all these types of content. It didn't work for me with `AVG()` so I thought I coult devide the content sums by the number of group members.
The query to get the members of each group is this

```
SELECT access_collections.id, COUNT(access_collection_membership.user_guid)
FROM access_collection_membership
INNER JOIN access_collections ON access_collections.id=access_collection_membership.access_collection_id
GROUP BY access_collections.id
```

I know my SUM()-Functions should be replaced by a COUNT()-Function but it didn`t work for me after several hours of trying.
I would be very glad if someone could help me :)
If you need more information please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an answer by myself.

As expected I had to (or at least I did) change the SUM()-Function into a COUNT-Function. For one example column the proper COUNT()-Function is

`SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN system_log.object_subtype="blog" AND system_log.event="create" THEN system_log.object_subtype END) AS "Number of blog entries"`...

On top of that query I built the average (also for that one example column) as following.

```
SELECT 
access_collections.id AS "Group ID", 
access_collections.name AS "Group",
TRUNCATE(AVG(blog),2) AS "Average amount of blog entries"
FROM (SELECT system_log.performed_by_guid,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN system_log.object_subtype="blog" AND system_log.event="create" THEN system_log.object_subtype END) AS blog
      FROM system_log GROUP BY system_log.performed_by_guid) ttemp

INNER JOIN users_entity ON users_entity.guid=ttemp.performed_by_guid
INNER JOIN access_collection_membership ON access_collection_membership.user_guid=users_entity.guid
INNER JOIN access_collections ON access_collections.id=access_collection_membership.access_collection_id

GROUP BY access_collections.id
ORDER BY access_collections.name
```